# I need help for Calculating "Big O"

Tags: big-o

the first problem;

```
sum = 0;

for i = 1 to n; i++
 {   
 for j = 1 to i * i; j++
    {
    for k = 1 to j; k++
       sum ++;
    }
 }
```

and the

Second problem;

```
sum = 0;

for i = 1 to n
  {  
  for j = 1 to i * i
    {
    if j mod i == 0
      {  
      for k = 1 to j
           sum ++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Hi I am new in IT and I need a help (actually two :D )

I met with "big o" few days before and while I was studying about it I found this address, and actualy I learn manythings from here...

but most of the examples about "big o" were just for explaining it, here I have two questions. After my calculations I found the big o for the first one as O(n^5) and for the second one O(n^3). but these values were too huge...

therefore I am here, I need your help... (even you can write what ever the result is without explanation but please help me about these questions)

Thanks as advance...

Comment: Can you fix the indenting or add braces so we know which loops end where?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the definition of big-O is that a function *g(x)* is *O(f(x))* if *g(x)* ≤ *kf(x)* for some constant *k*.

In other words, big-O tells you some idea of how fast a function grows; if it's $O(n)* it grows proportional to the length of the input.  What you're counting, and details of the computation, are hidden in the constant.

Here's some examples:

```
for i from 1 to n {
  do something 
}
```

is *O(n)*.  You go through the *n* items once each.

```
for i from 1 to n {
}
for i from 1 to n {
}
```

twice in sequence is still *O(n)*, because you're looking at each of the *n* items twice.  That's *2n* which is still *O(n)*.

On the other hand,

```
for i from 1 to n {
   for j from 1 to n {

   }
 }
```

is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* because for each step of *i*, you go through *1-n* for *j*.

Straighten out the indentation of your code so we're sure what you're doing, and see if those examples help.

Update

These are pretty amusing questions, come to think of it.

- the `i*i` term

Consider what the values of `i*i`, ie, i<sup>2</sup> will be.  At worst, i==n and so j is `1,4,9,16...(n*n)`.  What's the sum of x<sup>2</sup> for x from 1 to n?  (Hint: 1/6(...)(...), now you fill in the blanks.)

- the if ... mod term

when will that term be true?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but the things which confuse me are; the "if" condition of second question and "i*i" case for the first question, how these thinks effects the "big o"

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply after some more calculations I have changed my mind as O(n^7) for the first case and O(n^3) for the second case. I am not sure that either it is true or not, can you help me again (  please :D )